# What is maximum rate at which message can be pushed to aws sqs?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I have many services which will run on million of devices, each services pushing a message to common  sqs queue. I want to the maximum limit at which messages in sqs can be pushed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no limit on the message rate, but there is a limit on the number of in-flight messages (varies whether it's a FIFO or standard queue): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-limits.html

Comment: I got the point of inflight message but my problem is I am trying to send about 10000 messages to the queue per second and some are being lost

Comment: @Anonymous ...no.  None of them should ever be lost.  The most likely culprit here is improper handling by your application -- swallowing exceptions, deleting before (instead of after) processing, etc.  Every message sent to SQS returns a MessageId to the sender snd that same ID is also visible to the recipient, so you can trace every message end-to-end.  CloudWatch metrics on sends vs. receives should also agree.